# R - d3heatmap - implement breaks

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

I am trying to plot a heatmap using the `d3heatmap` package.
Unfortunately, I have not been successful yet in implementing certain breaks using the option `breaks=...` as in `heatmap` or `heatmap.2`.
This yields just funny results, I am not even sure whether I am doing something wrong or whether the function just ignores `breaks`.

For example, I tried:

```
breaks = c(seq(-10, -2), seq(-2, -1.65), seq(-1.65, 1.65), seq(1.65, 2), seq(2, 10)
```

and

```
breaks = c(-10, -2, -1.65, 1.65, 2, 10)
```

with

```
colors = c("red", "yellow", "green", "yellow", "red")
```

but nothing seems to work properly.

Any suggestions?

Here's the `dput` of my data:

```
 > dput(mat)
 structure(c(-0.04, NA, 0.59, NA, 0.675, 0.96, 1.09, 0.445, NA, 
 0.545, NA, NA, 0.09, -1.11, NA, 0.99, 0.13, 0.215, 1.425, 0, 
 NA, 0.69, 0.805, NA, 0.69, 1.22, NA, 0.3, NA, 0.025, NA, 0.075, 
 0.36, -0.94, NA, -0.31, 0.26, 1.02, -1.19, NA, NA, -0.77, NA, 
 -1.48, 1.05, 0.48, NA, NA, NA, 1.49, -1.285, NA, 0.76, 1.14, 
 -0.62, NA, NA, NA, 0.95, NA, NA, -0.12, 0.49, NA, 2.31, NA, -0.33, 
 0.85, NA, -1.7, -1.63, NA, -1.12, 0.135, -0.18, NA, -0.245, NA, 
 -0.2, -0.2, 0.23, -0.11, NA, 0.3, -0.81, 0.04, 0.18, -0.7, 0.53, 
 0.44, -0.49, 0.28, 0.26, 0.06, 0.265, 0.21, 0.06, -0.175, 0.365, 
 0.255, 1.25, -0.35, 0.16, 0.125, 0.825, 0.08, 0.02, -0.02, 0.99, 
 0.79, -0.23, 0.06, NA, 0.36, -0.64, -0.195, 1.19, -0.29, 0.915, 
 NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2, 0.1, NA, 0.04, 0.33, NA, 1.46, 2.36, NA, 
 -0.92, 1.295, NA, NA, 0.8, NA, 1.09, 1.45, 5.42, NA, NA, NA, 
 1.69, 3.43, NA, 0.55), .Dim = c(37L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("AT", 
 "BE", "BG", "CEE", "CH", "CN", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "EA", "EE", 
 "EMU", "ES", "EU", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "HR", "HU", "IE", 
 "IT", "JP", "LU", "NL", "PL", "PT", "RO", "RS", "RU", "SE", "SI", 
 "SK", "TR", "UA", "UK", "US"), c("Credit Risk", "Funding and liquidity Risk", 
 "Macro Risk", "Market Risk")))
```

And the code I am running:

```
d3heatmap(abs(mat),
          dendrogram = "none",
          breaks = c(0,1.65,2,10),
          col = c("green", "yellow", "red"),
          na.rm = TRUE)
```

The same function using `heatmap.2` works perfectly, though.

Comment: Could you provide a minimum, reproducible example?

Comment: Just provided the `dput`

Comment: Why are you running `abs(mat)` if your breaks are specified for negative values as well? I don't think that's needed, given the fact that your breaks are symmetrical, no?

Comment: I was just trying several specifications and in the last one I used `abs(mat)` with only green yellow and red to see it more clearly. But this should make no difference, yes.

Comment: The heatmap actually works, what I think you want, is discrete rather than continuous colors right? If so, the package `scales` can be used to do that, according to the documentation. BTW, if you want to make sure someone gets your reply, ping them with @ and then username.

Comment: Thanks @erasmortg - but for me it's not really working: I get shades between green-yellow-red, yes, but I have for example a field with the value 1.7 which is something between yellow and green, when it should actually be something between yellow and red, because it's over 1.65.

I tried some specifications with `col_bin` from `scales` but that did not really work out either. I get the palette I want but not the right scale - so it seems as if the `domain`-option is just ignored. Maybe I can try creating an asymmetric palette with `RColorBrewer` - just working on this.

Comment: I think I see the values that you mean. I think this might be expected behavior, as 1.7 (even though closer to 2) is closer to the lower values given a range that goes until 10.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the issue here. I just tried it with changing 10 to 2.1 - no effect. And also removing the `breaks`-argument completely: also no effect. So I probably have to find another solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function d3heatmap simply does not have a 'breaks' argument. If it gets passed in as an argument it is silently ignored. (See ?d3heatmap.)

The heatmap.2 function in the gplots package on the other hand *does* have a "breaks" argument. That explains the difference in behaviour.

Luckily, it is still possible to get the desired behaviour by passing an appropriate 'colors' function to d3heatmap. It works as follows.

First the example data:

```
mat <- structure(c(-0.04, NA, 0.59, NA, 0.675, 0.96, 1.09, 0.445, NA, 
                   0.545, NA, NA, 0.09, -1.11, NA, 0.99, 0.13, 0.215, 1.425, 0, 
                   NA, 0.69, 0.805, NA, 0.69, 1.22, NA, 0.3, NA, 0.025, NA, 0.075, 
                   0.36, -0.94, NA, -0.31, 0.26, 1.02, -1.19, NA, NA, -0.77, NA, 
                   -1.48, 1.05, 0.48, NA, NA, NA, 1.49, -1.285, NA, 0.76, 1.14, 
                   -0.62, NA, NA, NA, 0.95, NA, NA, -0.12, 0.49, NA, 2.31, NA, -0.33, 
                   0.85, NA, -1.7, -1.63, NA, -1.12, 0.135, -0.18, NA, -0.245, NA, 
                   -0.2, -0.2, 0.23, -0.11, NA, 0.3, -0.81, 0.04, 0.18, -0.7, 0.53, 
                   0.44, -0.49, 0.28, 0.26, 0.06, 0.265, 0.21, 0.06, -0.175, 0.365, 
                   0.255, 1.25, -0.35, 0.16, 0.125, 0.825, 0.08, 0.02, -0.02, 0.99, 
                   0.79, -0.23, 0.06, NA, 0.36, -0.64, -0.195, 1.19, -0.29, 0.915, 
                   NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2, 0.1, NA, 0.04, 0.33, NA, 1.46, 2.36, NA, 
                   -0.92, 1.295, NA, NA, 0.8, NA, 1.09, 1.45, 5.42, NA, NA, NA, 
                   1.69, 3.43, NA, 0.55), .Dim = c(37L, 4L),
                   .Dimnames = list(c("AT", "BE", "BG", "CEE", "CH", "CN", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "EA", "EE", "EMU", "ES", "EU", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "HR", "HU", "IE", "IT", "JP", "LU", "NL", "PL", "PT", "RO", "RS", "RU", "SE", "SI", "SK", "TR", "UA", "UK", "US"), c("Credit Risk", "Funding and liquidity Risk", "Macro Risk", "Market Risk")))
```

Suppose we want the following three color bins: blue for values < 0, green for values >= 0 but < 2, and red for values >= 2. We then define the corresponding ordered list of colors.

```
palette <- c("blue", "green", "red")
```

We also define the boundary values of the color bins. These values must include the domain boundaries.

```
mi <- min(mat, na.rm = TRUE)
ma <- max(mat, na.rm = TRUE)
breaks <- c(mi, 0, 2, ma)
```

We can now define a color interpolation function which maps a value in [0,1] onto a color, respecting our color bins. The 'scales' package comes to help here.

```
install.package('scales') # if needed
library(scales)
colorFunc <- col_bin(palette, bins = rescale(breaks))
```

The breaks originally defined in the domain of our data needed to be rescaled to [0,1]. The 'rescale' function in the 'scales' package handled that.

Small detail: the low boundary of a bin is *included* in the bin, but the high boundary is *excluded*. So the value 0 will be green, anything between 0 and 2 will be green too, but 2 will be red.

We can now plot the heat map.

```
d3heatmap(mat, dendrogram = "none", colors = colorFunc, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Okay, now I'm running into the next problem: what if the min or max of my data is greater or smaller than the threshold (e.g. my min is 0.5 but the threshold is 0)? Any solution @WhiteViking ?